# I can't get image from Google Map with help of Drawing Cache in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, drawingcache

I have this code in layout:

```
<FrameLayout>    
        <fragment
            ...
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
        </fragment>    
</FrameLayout>
```

But when i try use drawing cache, screenshot have only zoom bar (with + and - buttons) and text "Google" in left corner.
I use next code for getting image:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.frame);
view.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);
view.destroyDrawingCache();
view.buildDrawingCache();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
routeScreen = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? i mean google map v2 directly provide `SnapshotReadyCallback` for the snap shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because the map is drawn using OpenGL and the pixel data is stored in the GPU.

Have a look at Google Map's [GoogleMap.snapshot()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#snapshot(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback)) method in order to capture a screenshot of the map.